# Create docker file with a sql server and .NET SDK

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, testing, integration-testing

I would like to run my C# integration tests in a Docker environment. It is a .NET Core 7.0 test project. For the integration tests to be useful it needs a MS SQL Server. For this purpose the following docker image is available: [SQL Server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server). I want to copy my test project into the same Docker container and run it there. For this I need .NET Core so that I can run "dotnet test". What is the best way to achieve this?

I have also not been able to merge the docker image from SQL Server with the one for [.NET SDK](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-nightly-sdk):

Can I build the test project and then copy it to the Docker container from SQL Server and then run it (if so how?) or can I install .NET SDK on the Docker container from SQL Server?

Here is my current dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest AS final

WORKDIR /app

USER root
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
       wget \
       ca-certificates \
    \
    # Install Microsoft package feed
    && wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    \
    # Install .NET
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        dotnet-runtime-7.0 \
    \
    # Cleanup
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN ((/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started") 

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
```

Comment: Aside... the SQL Server service isn't meant to run as `root`, you should switch back to `USER mssql` before running up the service.

Comment: So what's the problem? Are you getting some kind of error message?

Comment: The problem is that with this dockerfile I only install the runtime of .NET. However, I need the SDK. That means the command "dotnet test" is not available. Is there an easy solution here than to install everything manually? Can I somehow merge the two referenced docker images (sql server and .NET SDK)? If this is not possible, how can I install the .NET SDK?

Comment: Instead of installing `dotnet-runtime-7.0` have you tried installing `dotnet-sdk-7.0`? But is there really any need to have it running in the same container as SQL Server? Docker containers should be task-specific, each one doing as little as possible, and you orchestrate functionality by creating a composition of containers using `docker-compose` (and a `docker-compose.yml` file).